# No Unity desktop after log in to 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am able to log in with my user id but when I do I get only the desktop background. Unity apparently doesn't load.  I get no Launcher down the left side of my screen and no Panel across the top.  I get only a mouse arrow.  I'm able to bring up various windows by right-clicking my mouse or pressing a windows key on my keyboard.  I would think there would be a way to boot Unity, but I don't see anything in the windows that I'm able to open.  Also, I can't figure out anyway to get a command line.  There doesn't even seem to be a way from the screen to shut down the computer.  I have to use the button on my console.

I have just installed 14.04 in parallel to 10.04 in a dual boot arrangement with Windows 7.  I have Windows and Linux running on separate hard drives.  Things were working ok for the first few days after the install, but today this problem occurred.

Thank you for any help.

Bob Wetmore

Comment: Are you sharing a home directory for the 10.04 and 14.04 installations?

Comment: To Sneetsher.  I did see and use the first solution from the reference you mentioned.  I'm back in business; I think it worked for me.  To ubfan1: I'm not sure.  I copied stuff that was in my home directory in 10.04 to 14.04, which I happened to find in some strangely named directory.  Thank you both for your information and help.